# Storage access key and seccrect key asp.net in production

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, storage, .net-6.0, aws-secrets-manager

I wonder how can I store my access key and secret key of AWS in ASP.NET core when I deployed. I'm using .net 6

I have a block code here to retrieve secret values from the AWS secret manager. But there is any way to store the 'access-key-xxx' and 'secret-key-xxx' in a production mode?

```
builder.Configuration.AddSecretsManager(credentials: new 
BasicAWSCredentials("access-key-xxx","secret-key-xxx"), 
region: RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast1, configurator: options =>
{

options.SecretFilter = entry => entry.Name.StartsWith($"{env}_{appName}_");
options.KeyGenerator = (_, s) => s.Replace($"{env}_{appName}_", string.Empty)
    .Replace("__", ":");
});
```

Tks for you time.

Comment: Your real question is how to store the AWS credentials, not secrets. More precisely, how to avoid using BasicAWSCredentials. Where is this deployed? In an EC2 instance you could [use IAM roles and avoid credentials entirely](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-hosm.html). You could [use profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-assign.html) or even load the keys from environment variables configured on the instance or container

Comment: I'm deploying using docker image in azure

Comment: Why are you using the Amazon SDK and tags then???? You should be asking how to use Azure Key Vault not Amazon Secrets Manager. Instead of IAM you have Azure AD accounts so there's no need to store credentials to the key vault.